# Inheritence and casting with eigen3 in C++

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to extend a eigen3 type as follows:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> CMatrixImgParent;

class CMatrixImg : public  CMatrixImgParent
{
  public:
    CMatrixImg() : CMatrixImgParent() {}

    int Dummy(const char *filename) const {};
};
```

and then do some arithmetics with eigen3.

```
CMatrixImg img1, img2, imgSum;
imgSum = img1 + img2;
```

But this doesn't work as I with g++ get the error:

```
g++ -o bug.o -c -O2 -I/usr/include/eigen3 bug.cc
bug.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
bug.cc:17:10: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'CMatrixImg' and 'const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<unsigned char>, const Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, -1, -1, 1>, const Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, -1, -1, 1> >')
   imgSum = img1 + img2;
          ^
bug.cc:17:10: note: candidate is:
bug.cc:5:7: note: CMatrixImg& CMatrixImg::operator=(const CMatrixImg&)
 class CMatrixImg : public  CMatrixImgParent
       ^
bug.cc:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<unsigned char>, const Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, -1, -1, 1>, const Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, -1, -1, 1> >' to 'const CMatrixImg&'
scons: *** [bug.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Tue Jul 16 18:31:18
```

Of course I can get around this by some explicit casting like so:

```
(*(CMatrixImgParent*)&imgSum) = img1 + img2;
```

But this is very ugly.

Is there any simple code that I can place in the class definition to get around the need for this type of casting?

Comment: The compiler wants to build a CMatrixImg out of a CMatrixImgParent but doesn't know how. If you have a recipe, explain it to the compiler. There are three kinds of recipes to build X out of Y: constructors, assignment operators, and conversion operators. The latter goes to the definition of Y so you cannot do that. Try the other two options.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. All I needed to do was to define an assignment operator from a CMatrixImgParent and put the "ugly" casting in it. I'll put the result in a separate answer for postority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html#InheritingFromMatrix) suggests that inheriting from `Eigen::Matrix` (which is essentially `CMatrixImgParent` in your example) should only be a last resort, and that a macro-driven approach that allows you to add members to `Eigen::Matrix` directly is preferred:

> Before inheriting from Matrix, be really, i mean REALLY sure that using EIGEN_MATRIX_PLUGIN is not what you really want (see previous section). If you just need to add few members to Matrix, this is the way to go.

The macro approach is described as:

> In this section we will see how to add custom methods to MatrixBase. Since all expressions and matrix types inherit MatrixBase, adding a method to MatrixBase make it immediately available to all expressions ! A typical use case is, for instance, to make Eigen compatible with another API.
>
> You certainly know that in C++ it is not possible to add methods to an existing class. So how that's possible ? Here the trick is to include in the declaration of MatrixBase a file defined by the preprocessor token EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN

The example they give is

```
class MatrixBase {
// methods ...
#ifdef EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN
#include EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN
#endif
};
```

So, it seems that you could follow this approach to define your `int Dummy(const char* filename) const` method.  If you actually want to inherit from `Eigen::Matrix`, it seems that you will need to write an assignment operator yourself, as n.m. alluded to in the comments.

Comment: Ah, 9 seconds after I wrote this, you indicated you went with the assignment operator approach.  At least you avoided some macros. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an assignment operator from `CMatrixImgParent` to `CMatrixImg` class solves the casting problem:

```
class CMatrixImg : public  CMatrixImgParent
{
  public:
    // Constructor
    CMatrixImg() : CMatrixImgParent() {}

    // This is needed for assignment of arithmetic results.
    CMatrixImg& operator=(const CMatrixImgParent& Other) {
      *((CMatrixImgParent*)this) = Other;
      return *this;
    }
    int Dummy(const char *filename) const {};
};
```

But see also the answer by RyanMcK that might be preferable for eigen3.